# ember folder contains only gitkeep file

Tags: ember.js

after creating a folder in ember I see nothing but a file called ".gitkeep" in all the folders such as routes and templates(in every folder). This problem seems to be repeating after trying to install many times..

Answer (score 2):

`.gitkeep` files are here to force git to commit the directory. By default git do not version folder and an ember-cli project is by default a git repository. (unless you specified `--skip-git`).

A new ember-cli project should contain at least `app/templates/application.hbs` because this is all you need to start.
You can add routes and controllers with `ember generate route` and `ember generate controller`.